# Bootstrap 1 Line Footer Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I have a problem that I've been working on all day, unfortunately without success.

In Bootstrap I want a sticky footer that consists of only one row with several menu items which turns into one row for every item on screens with less then 1000px.

[One Row Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmKDr.png)
[More Row Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzZ7L.png)

Unfortunately, I always fail because the footer is responsive and stays at the bottom of the page. I would be very happy if anyone. could send the appropriate HTML and CSS code.

Here's my code:

```html
<style>
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .footer-purple {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .footer-content {
    padding: 30px 50px 50px;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .footer-navigation {
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .footer-link {
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-content footer-purple">
    <nav class="footer-navigation">
      <a class="footer-link">
                Test
            </a>
      <a class="footer-link">
                Test 2
            </a>
    </nav>
  </div>

</footer>
```

It looks like that: https://prnt.sc/sj02x6

Comment: weclome to Stacloverflow! please provide minimum code of the issue or provide a working demo.

Comment: We would be very happy if you could send the HTML and CSS code which you tried.

Comment: Here's my code: https://hasteb.in/pizowiwe.xml, it looks like that: https://prnt.sc/sj02x6